# Evaluate $I=\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{z}}{z^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!z^{n-k}\ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $0\leq k\leq n$.

Evaluate the following integral:

$$I=\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{z}}{z^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!z^{n-k}\ dz$$

---

**My Attempt**

The integrand is not analytic inside $|z|=1$, thus it is not necessarily true that $I=0$. For that reason my best guess would be to use *Cauchy's Integral Formula* for derivatives:

$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint\limits_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$$

If I substitute $z_0=0$:

$$2\pi if^{(n)}(0)=\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{n!f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\ dz$$

Equating the RHS with the desired $I$ we receive:

$$2\pi if^{(n)}(0)=\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{n!f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\ dz=\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{z}}{z^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!z^{n-k}\ dz=I$$

So actually, the analytic function $f(z)$ I am looking for is:

$$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!z^{n-k}$$

Since if I can prove $f(z)$ is analytic, I would get that:

$$I=2\pi if^{(n)}(0)$$

Which seems like a *much* easier thing to calculate. However, I am still not sure how to calculate that. I didn't put much effort to it, because I have a more basic problem - I don't know how to prove that $f(z)$ I found is anayltic inside $|z|=1$.

I would be glad to hear your thoughts, or maybe a more clever solution that you thought of yourself.

**Important: I haven't learned Laurent Series yet**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k!\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^{k+1}}\,dz.$$
But
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^{k+1}}\,dz=\frac{2\pi i}{k!} f^{(k)}(0)$$
by Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives,
where $f(z)=e^z$. Then $f^{(k)}(z)=e^z$
 and so
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k!\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^{k+1}}\,dz
=\sum_{k=0}^n2\pi i\frac{k!}{k!}e^0=2\pi i(n+1).$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you can change the order of integrating and summing. Is it because $n$ is finite?

Comment: Yes, there is no difficulty with interchanging integrals and **finite** sums. @AmitZach

Answer (score 2):

Your function is analytic on the whole complex plane.

All you have to do is evaluate $\int \frac  {e^{z}} {z^{n+1}} z^{n-k}dz$ for  each $k$ between $0$ and $n$ , mulitly this by $k!$ and add.

$\int_{|z|=1} \frac {e^{z}  } {z^{k+1}}dz=2\pi i \frac 1 {k!}$ since the residue at $0$ is $\frac 1 {k!}$. Hence the answer is $2\pi i (n+1)$. You can also get this from Cauchy's Integral Formula instead of Residue Theorem.